# rails plugin vs bundle gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

This two commands seem to generate practically the same thing

```
rails plugin new __name__ 
bundle gem __name__
```

There is a hidden detail I haven't notice?

which one do you use, and basically, why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can all generate a barebone gem but they are different.

`rails plugin new` could generate a dummy app inside `test`, and a basic `test_helper`, which would be very handy if you want to add some functional/integration tests in gem. You can also revise that a bit to use Rspec. `bundle gem` would not do that.

If you develop the gem for Rails and need such tests, `rails plugin` would be better. Otherwise `bundle` or a gem generating gem `jeweller`.

Comment: But you usually always need a test module no?

Comment: Some gems need unit testing only, dummy is not always needed.

Comment: ah yes, ok, I take that. Thanks.

Comment: There is also another alternative - jeweller gem, taking care of publishing and github, very handy for pure Ruby gem.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are more or less deprecated in favor of gems in recent versions of Rails.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, running `rails plugin my_gem` simply creates a 'my_gem' directory in the root of your rails app.

It's not too much different from running `bundle gem my_gem` except that it stubs out a couple of test files,  and runs bundle install.

This may be useful if you're creating a gem that's made to be run on rails - where you need a "rails environment" (see the test/dummy/app directory).

Still, if you do it this way, it appears the gem is added right into the root of your rails project.  You could always move it, but if you were to run bundle gem you could do so wherever you want.

Comment: yes but according to the doc rails plugins new is used for creating gem too : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html

Comment: @xdotcommer, instead of reading and citing others, you need to read the original doc and get your hands dirty.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm working off of my knowledge of the situation - I wasn't familiar with gemified plugins - so i thought this would be nicer than saying lmgtfy since the other post seemed in line with my understanding.